# How to list all my commits that contain specific word in gerrit web

Tags: gerrit

I find a issue with my merged commits with word `setw` in a gerrit project. I want to filter out these commits to fix the bug. When I search with `setw`, it shows lots of commits include mine. However, when I use `setw AND owner:self` to search, it shows none of commits of mine. Am I missing something?

**So the general question is how to list all my commits that contain specific word in gerrit web?**

Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your approach, I tested here and it worked pretty well. Are you the owner of the change, right?

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira, yes, actually the repo is open for all registers

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira Go through the document of [gerrit search](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-search.html), it seems it does not support to search changes with specified word. If `setw` exists in the comments, the commit will be filter out. If it is in the code, it won't

Comment: Yes, you can't search in the code. When you said that you're searching in the "commits" I thought you were searching in the commit messages not in the code. I just answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't search in the code. You only can search in the commit messages, comments, votes and other Gerrit data.